# Ember.js - How to handle error with DS.store.find() method

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

this maybe simple but I can't find an answer on the web. My Ember app is using the Ds.store.find method to find a user in the store and the backend database if not in the store. I'm using Firebase for the backend database and their EmberFire adapter. When the database do not find the record, the find method crash with the following message in the Google debug tool:

***"Error while processing route: user.index No model was found for 'user' Error: No model was found for 'user'"***

How can I handle this error before and have instead a alert showing to the user that they need to login?

The UserRoute code is:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      var _authUID = this.get('firebase').authUID
      return this.store.find('user', _authUID);
    },
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing actually doesn't mean that the user isn't being found, it means that you have not defined a user model in ember-data.

You need to define a model like this:

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    // Model attributes
});
```

Comment: As you can tell, I'm just starting in JS and with Ember... Thanks for your answer, it fixed the issue and helped me.

Comment: No worries! Good luck with moving forward, Ember is a great framework and just takes some time to learn :)